# Dynamic DbContext per user logged in using Dependency Injection with interfaces

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dynamic, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I am working on building a multi-tenant web application (API) that will access different databases based upon the user that logs in. There will be a single database to manage user logins that contains the Server and Database information needed to build a connection string code side to build the DbContext for the particular user that is logged in. Here is the wire up from the lowest level to the controller:

GenericRepository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : GenericRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public GenericRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    { 
        //GenericRepositoryBase has the CRUD operations
    }
}
```

IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

    Task<TEntity> GetByID(object id);

    Task<ContextReturn> Insert(TEntity entity);

    Task<ContextReturn> Update(TEntity entityToDelete);

    Task<ContextReturn> Remove(TEntity entityToUpdate);
}
```

Specific Model Repository:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : GenericRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

Startup.cs in API contains:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
```

and finally the controller hookup:

```
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository { get; }

    public EmployeeController(
        IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        EmployeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        var data = EmployeeRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

All of which works just fine when working with a single DbContext declared in the startup as:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SystemManagementConnection"), sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(300)));
```

(In fact I am using this exact DI context appropriately named to access the user management database).

The problem presents itself when attempting to dynamically create the DbContext based upon the user logging in due to a couple of reasons:

1. When using DI in this manner you don't create the DbContext in the
   controller and pass it into the repository as I am using interfaces
   to access them. DI uses the DbContext declared in the startup to
   pass through, which I don't want for all repositories.
2. The Startup.cs isn't aware of any user information, so this can't be
   passed through any kind of method to build a DbContext based upon
   that information.

I attempted to resolve the first using the following:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>((ctx) => { DbContext context = DbContextFactory.Create(); return new EmployeeRepository(context); });
```

tied to:

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    public static DbContext Create()
    {
        var conn = GetConnectionString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn))
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
            return new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnectionId");
        }
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var data = "";

        return data;
    }
}
```

and then pass the IHttpContextAccessor into a constructor to access the user (I am sure you know where this is going already...), but of course that requires the class to not be static which then throws errors in the Startup.cs file. Essentially, this doesn't solve my problem.

The only other solution I can think of is to declare **ALL** of my DbContexts into the services of the Startup.cs file, but again, my repositories will still not know which one to use based upon the user.

Surely I am not the first person to encounter this. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step solution *based on the posted sources*:

1. Register the `IHttpContextAccessor` as singleton service.
2. Modify the `DbContextFactory` class and register as singleton service, now you're ready to request the `IHttpContextAccessor` service from class's constructor; then use it to build the connection string dynamic.
3. Add each repository implementation using the `Scoped` mode. And modify the implementation factory function to load the `DbContextFactory` service.

**Here an implementation example:**

`DbContextFactory` class:

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public DbContextFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public DbContext Create()
    {
        var conn = GetConnectionString();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
        return new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //--use the `_httpContext` to build the connection string dynamic
        var user = _httpContext?.HttpContext?.User;
        //...
        return "TODO";
    }
}
```

And the partial modifications to `ConfigureServices` method, located on `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<DbContextFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>(
        (servicesProvider) =>
        {
            var contextFactory = servicesProvider.GetService<DbContextFactory>();
            DbContext context = contextFactory.Create();
            return new EmployeeRepository(context);
        });
    ...
}
```

I hope it helps!